# Read from appsettings.json config file

Tags: c#, logging, configuration

I have the following config in my appsettings.json File

```
 {
  "AppSettings": {
    "MainUser": {
      "Name": "Urs",
      "Surname": "Barandun",
      "SesstionTimeInMin": "30",
    }
  },
```

And I'd like to create a custom configuration class and bind it. Eg:

```
MainUserConfiguration mainUserConfiguration = new MainUserConfiguration();
var configSection = config.GetSection("MainUserConfiguration");
configSection.Bind(mainUserConfiguration);
```

But, my code does not work. :/

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've provided, your appsettings file and the nested JSON for your configuration don't match up. A typical ASP.NET Core `appsettings.json` doesn't have a nested element called "AppSettings", and further you're getting a configuration section called "MainUserConfiguration" while your actual JSON just names that section "MainUser".

appsettings example:

```
{
  "MyFirstClass": {
    "Option1": "some string value",
    "Option2": 42
  },
  "MySecondClass": {
    "SettingOne": "some string value",
    "SettingTwo": 42
  }
}
```

In your code:

```
public class MyFirstClass
{
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public int Option2 { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondClass
{
    public string SettingOne { get; set; }
    public int SettingTwo { get; set; }
}
```

In your Startup.cs (presuming that's where you're accessing it with a defined `Configuration` object:

```
var myFirstClass = Configuration.GetSection("MyFirstClass").Get<MyFirstClass>();
var mySecondClass = Configuration.GetSection("MySecondClass").Get<MySecondClass>();
Console.WriteLine($"The answer is always {myFirstClass.Option2}");
```